# Formatting a table in R

Tags: r, text, formatting, reshape2

I have data like

```
            147 147 231 231
2011_15_1   99  106 152 156
2011_15_2   99  102 150 156
2011_15_3   99  99  152 156
2011_15_7   99  106 152 156
```

and I would like to reformat it to become:

```
            147     231
2011_15_1   99      152
            106     156
2011_15_2   99      150
            102     156
2011_15_3   99      152
            99      156
2011_15_7   99      152
            106     156
```

I have tried reading the table into R and using the 'reshape2' package and the melt() function, but I am unsure how to make it collapse columns with the same name into narrow-form.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` + `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = row.names(.)) %>%
  gather(key, value, -date) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(key = gsub("[.]1$", "", key)) %>%
  group_by(date, key) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-id)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   date [4]
       date  X147  X231
*     <chr> <int> <int>
1 2011_15_1    99   152
2 2011_15_1   106   156
3 2011_15_2    99   150
4 2011_15_2   102   156
5 2011_15_3    99   152
6 2011_15_3    99   156
7 2011_15_7    99   152
8 2011_15_7   106   156
```

Note:

1. `read.table` does two conversions to the column names when reading in the data: attaching `X` in front and `.1` as a suffix for repeated column names. This is because neither pure numbers nor identical column names are valid.
2. What I basically did was first convert rownames to the first column `date`,
3. transform the data from wide to long form (`gather`),
4. remove all `.1` suffixes in the `key` column,
5. added an `id` that is `group_by` `date` and `key` to make each row unique,
6. then finally transform the data back to wide form (`spread`) using the new `key` and `value` columns.

Data:

```
df = read.table(text="         147 147 231 231
                2011_15_1   99  106 152 156
                2011_15_2   99  102 150 156
                2011_15_3   99  99  152 156
                2011_15_7   99  106 152 156", header = TRUE)
```